# How to define the value of other invalid input in this "if block" for converting string to object in c++?

Tags: c++, string, object, if-statement

I am trying to convert `string` to `object` in the following piece of code. How can I set the value of any other unrelated invalid input?

```
object stringToObject(string input){
    if (input == "rock")
        return object::rock;
    else if (input == "paper")
        return object::paper;
    else if (input == "scisors")
        return object::scissors;
}
```

**Update:** The entire code, in case it helps, is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

enum object { rock, paper, scissors };

object stringToObject(string input){
    if (input == "rock")
        return object::rock;
    else if (input == "paper")
        return object::paper;
    else if (input == "scisor")
        return object::scissors;
    else if (input !== "mock")
        return cout>>"Invalid input";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    string player1Input, player2Input;
    cout << "Enter input";
    cin >> player1Input >> player2Input;

    object player1Choice = stringToObject(player1Input);
    object player2Choice = stringToObject(player2Input);

    switch (player1Choice) {
        case object::rock:
            cout << "blah";
            break;
        case object::paper:
            cout << "blah blah";
            break;
        case object::scissors:
            cout << "blah blah blah";
            break;
    }

    switch (player2Choice) {
        case object::rock:
            cout << "blah";
            break;
        case object::paper:
            cout << "blah blah";
            break;
        case object::scissors:
            cout << "blah blah blah";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to check the basics of enum

Comment: Do you have an error value of `object`? Do you want wrong input to be an error? What is the [mre] for this question really?

Comment: @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica Yes, I want the wrong input to be an error.

Comment: Either add an error value to `enum class object`, or `throw` an exception in the `else` branch, or return a `std::pair<object, bool>` where the second indicates if the first is valid.

Comment: Good. What sort of error? Do you want to just guard against programmer mistakes? Or notify the calling context that a bad string was passed in, and let it handle it?

Comment: @ No I just want any input other than "rock" paper" "scissors" inserted by the user not being accepted.

Comment: Not accepted and then what? There is no magic here, you have to decide how severe is the error and how it propagates. Simply "not accepting" is as simple as ending the function with a call to `std::terminate`.

Comment: How should I add an else branch. I know  (else cout >> "invalid input";) does not work.

Comment: The idiomatic way of handling errors in C++ is [exceptions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exception-handling-c/). It's a model of error handling that doesn't force you to modify your data flow. The alternative is to use [error codes](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/09/04/using-error-codes-effectively/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the following suits your purpose:

```
enum object {rock, paper, scissors, invalid};

object stringToObject(string input){
if (input == "rock") return object::rock;
else if (input == "paper") return object::paper;
else if (input == "scissors") return object::scissors;
return object::invalid;}
.
.
.
switch(player1Choice){
case object::rock: cout << ""; break;
case object::paper: cout << ""; break;
case object::scissors: cout << ""; break;
default: cout << "Invalid choice"; break;}
.
.
.
```